# Weka Text Mining Naive Bayes

Tags: weka, naivebayes

I have a question about Textmining in Weka. So I have 4 different categories. And I want the data to be classified into those categories. In addition I want the data to be predicted whether they are positive/ negative or neutral.
So here is my training data before using any filter:

```
@relation QueryResult

@attribute class {Qualität,Bord,Kite,Harness}
@attribute text {evo,foil,end,fin,edg}

@data
Qualität,evo
Bord,foil
Kite,end
Harness,fin
Qualität,edg
```

This is my java code:

```
 Instances train = new Instances(loadInstancesForWeka("root","",sqlCommand));
 train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 2);

 NominalToString filter1 = new NominalToString();
 filter1.setInputFormat(train);
 train = Filter.useFilter(train, filter1);


 //filter
 StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector(); 
 filter.setInputFormat(train);
 train = Filter.useFilter(train, filter);

// test2 are the testing instances
     naive.buildClassifier(train);
     for (int i = 0; i < test2.numInstances(); i++) {
                double index = naive.classifyInstance(test2.instance(i));
    }
```

So by now my data are classified into the four categories Qualität, Bord, Kite, Harness.
How can I now use naive bayes to classify them also into positive/ negative/ neutral?

Comment: Do you have training data where the instances are classified as positive, negative or neutral? Or are you looking for an existing sentiment analysis model?